# Using intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I would like to show that the following equation has at least two solutions for all $m\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$
$$
mx^4-(3m-1)x^3-6x^2+(2m+1)x+m-6=0.
$$
**My attempt.**

Let $f(x)=mx^4-(3m-1)x^3-6x^2+(2m+1)x+m-6$.
I try to rewrite the equation as
$$
m(x^4-3x^3+2x+1)+(x^2+1)(x-6)=0.
$$
I use intermediate value theorem to prove that $x^4-3x^3+2x+1=0$ has two solution $x_1, x_2$ such that
$$
1<x_1<2<x_2<3.
$$
Then $f(x_1)<0$ and $f(x_2)<0$. We consider two cases of m as

**Case 1.** $m>0$

Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=+\infty$, there exist $x_3<1$ and $x_4>3$ such that
$$
f(x_3)>0, \quad f(x_4)>0. 
$$
Again, using intermediate theorem we obtain that $f(x)=0$ has at least two solutions.

**Case 2.** m<0

I cannnot deal with this case.

Thank you for all kind help.

Comment: I wouldn't re-write it. Try $f(n)$s, special values at integers then consider cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: to guess the number of solutions, plot the function
\begin{equation}
g(x) = \frac{-(x^2 +1)(x-6)}{x^4 - 3 x^2 + 2 x + 1}
\end{equation}
This could also give ideas of results to prove with the intermediate value  theorem.

For some values of $m$, there is no solution.

Answer (score 2):

When $m>0$, all you need is one $x$ such that $f(x)<0$; that guarantees two roots since $f$ goes to $+\infty$ at $\pm\infty$. What you did is a good way to find such $x$.

When $m<0$, what you want to show is not true. For instance for $m=-1$, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=max+%28x%5E4-3x%5E3%2B2x%2B1%29%28-1%29%2B%28x%5E2%2B1%29%28x-6%29) reports that $f(x)<-6$ for all $x$.